# How to update an attribute in one query with dynamodb-data-mapper?

Tags: typescript, amazon-dynamodb, datamapper

The AWS CLI for DynamoDB can update an attribute using one query (without modifying the rest of the item), such as described here : https://www.dynamodbguide.com/updating-deleting-items

I try to do the same using dynamodb-data-mapper, but according to the following example it requires two queries : https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-data-mapper-js#update

Is there a way to achieve the update of an attribute in one query using dynamodb-data-mapper ?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use executeUpdateExpression : https://awslabs.github.io/dynamodb-data-mapper-js/packages/dynamodb-data-mapper/classes/datamapper.html#executeupdateexpression